# Should we avoid creating objects of a template parameter

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following function template:

```
template <typename T>
void init()
{
     std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(new T());
     //do some with it
}
```

the function template is intended to use in some other function as follows:

```
void bar()
{ 
    try{
        init<int>();
    } catch(___WHAT?___){ }
}
```

The thing is I don't know what ot do if the consturctor of `T` throwing an exception. I simply don't know what it can throw. Of course I could write `catch(...)` but that wasn't be good.

So, what should I do when I need to create objects of the template parameter?

Comment: Why catch(...) isn't good? What problem are you facing?

Comment: @PaoloM Because that catching all exception so I can't customize the handler if I need it...

Comment: If you want to customize it again a given exception type well ... you have to know that type...

Comment: Well, you should look at the documentation (or at the code, if you can) of T, to see what types of exceptions it can throw. In any case, you can't customize the handler if you don't know what exceptions it will throw...

Comment: If you were asking if there is a way to know all kind of exceptions a function can throw, like in Java, the answer is NO.

Comment: You could catch all and then give each class that T may assume a static handler so it can handle its own construction errors. So if you call init <ACertainT> () and it fails you call your static handler for ACertainT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you feel a need to handle exceptions.

In C++, you solve the relevant problems with RAII. The only thing your `init()` function should do is clean up the resources it allocated. The resources of `T` are already cleaned up, and the caller of `init` is responsible for dealing with the failure of `init`.

Comment: Well, I follow RAII in the `init` function wrapping dynamically allocated object of the type T in unqiue_ptr. What's wrong?

Comment: In that case, nothing - but why are you then trying to catch something? Note that `bar` calls `init<int>` and therefore knows that the only possible exception is `bad_alloc` (out of memory).

Comment: I just want to write log to make it simplier to detect such faalts.

Comment: @St.Antario: In that case, you can just catch `std::exception&`, log its `.what()` description, and re-throw.

Comment: BTW, what would happen if I didn;t wrap the creation into a smart pointer? I can't see what problem would appear in that case....

Comment: Still wouldn't be an issue - `new` recycles the raw memory if the ctor fails